# Is it possible to enable drag and drop gestures on windows 11 that were removed?

Tags: windows, taskbar, shortcuts, windows-11, drag-and-drop

Back when I used Windows 7 and 10, I had the ability to drag files and objects off windows, say, hover them over another open app on the taskbar, and it would focus on that window, allowing me to drop that file or object into that window.

There were quite a few drag-and-drop features like that, and I remember a lot of drag and drop features related to creating shortcuts from explorer and the start menu by dragging them to the desktop.

Now, if I want to create a shortcut, I have to use shell commands to open the Applications folder and manually create a shortcut from the list of applications, or if I want to drag a file to another window, I have to minimize everything and shrink the two windows so I can drag it and refocus onto the other window.

It's been one of the most repetitively irritating issues with Windows 11, hell, I can't even drag and drop an application onto the taskbar, I have to open the application, then right-click and pin it.

Is there a setting or registry option to enable these features?

I've had these convenient features since the first versions of Windows 7 I ever used, and then Windows 11 came around and so many of the convenience features are just gone.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways using which you can enable drag and drop in Windows 11. Refer [this article](https://devsjournal.com/how-to-enable-drag-and-drop-in-windows-11.html) for all the methods. I was using the registry method given in the link but it had some drawbacks. Now, I am using the Drag and Drop Toolbar for Windows 11 which is available on the [Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9PPR08FTRQ0K). It adds a replicated taskbar on the top of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

This feature has been reintroduced with the recent [Windows 11 22H2 update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/status-windows-11-22h2). After installing the update, the drag and drop on the taskbar should work again.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.